# Reactjs is there a way to combine multiple protected routers?

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a website that uses multiple protected routers
The app.js is shown like this:

```
class App extends Component{
 render(){
   return(
     <Switch> 
       <UserProtectedRoute exact path="/users" 
          UserDashboard={() => <User DashBoard /> />
       <UserProtectedProfileRouter exact path="/users/profile" 
          UserProtectedProfile={() => <UserProtectedProfile /> />
           ...
       <UserProtectedSettings exact path="/users/settings" 
          UserProtectedSettings={() => <UserProtectedSettings /> />
          ...
     </Switch>
   );
  }
 }
 export default App;
```

The protected router.js:

```
const UserProfileProtectedRoute = ({ UserProfilePage, token, ...rest }) => {
  {...conditions1}

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={() =>
        {conditions 2} ? (
          <UserProfilePage {...rest} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={"/login"} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

There are so many protected routers, and they all follow the same user log in auth(the protected conditions are the same).So I wonder is there a way to combine them together, all , at least a more convenient way to structure all my protected routers so I do not have to list all of them one by one.

Thanks so much :  )

Answer (score 1):

You can make your protected routes much more generic to enable you to only have to use one component. React Router has an [example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) on how to do protected routes in a more generic way.

Here's an example based on that will hopefully help you get it right.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children, token, ...rest }) => {


  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={() =>
        conditions2 ? (
          {children}
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={"/login"} />
        )
        }
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Official tutorial to protect the route is here, https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow.

I normally do a simple version as

```
   { isProtected && (
     <Switch>
         put all your routes here
     </Switch>
   ) }
```

Or wrap the if statement inside switch,

```
  <Switch>
    { isProtected && (<Route ... />) }
    <Redirect .... />
  </Switch>
```

Therefore you make sure it'll try to match with one route, otherwise redirect. The assumption of this approach is that your User profile or permission has been fully resolved at this point.